# Unable to properly view header.php

Tags: php, header, include

My directory structure is like this

- index.php ,
- images ,
- style,
- menu ,
- header.php ,
- pets

  - petsindex.php

When i include header.php for index.php it works but for petsindex.php it is working but stylesheet doesnot work and also images used in header.php don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because it's searching stylesheet files in pets/css.css

Try to change

```
path_to_css.css
```

to

```
/path_to_css.css
```

along do the same with images. Be sure you have your header.php in root of your web

Comment: yes i did this for css it works also but then it doesnot work for images used in header.php as they also require path change.

Comment: i want the same header file to be used in all pages but stored in different folders and when i do so it includes header.php but does not show css and images linked.

Comment: @ashish: as I said, prefix everything with /

Comment: what if there are 1000 pages using header and footer.php in different folders , then it will become really tiresome . I want to use a single file for whole website without changing anything , is there any way?

Comment: yes thats the only way out . But if u find anyother way please post it.Thanks.

Comment: Please show your support by [accepting my answer via button showed on image](http://i.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) if you want